# php mail function not working

Tags: php, sendmail

when i tried sending a mail using php mail function at localhost, i get the following error....what could be the issue....i even tried changing php.ini file and gave smtp host value my service provider value and it still dint work

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

Comment: `mailserver at "localhost" port 25` - Is there an smtp server supposed to be running on your machine?

Comment: no. i dont have any smtp server

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding the following code in the calling file did the trick

```
// xampp code fix      
ini_set( 'sendmail_from', "myself@my.com" ); \\ My usual e-mail address
ini_set( 'SMTP', "mail.bigpond.com" );  \\ My usual sender
ini_set( 'smtp_port', 25 );
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant sendmail_from - assumed 'sendmail_from' in C:\wamp\www\sample\cms\download.php on line 101

Notice: Use of undefined constant SMTP - assumed 'SMTP' in C:\wamp\www\sample\cms\download.php on line 102

Notice: Use of undefined constant smtp_port - assumed 'smtp_port' in C:\wamp\www\sample\cms\download.php on line 103

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Message rejected because (ITF152) [122.172.120.168] is blacklisted. in C:\wamp\www\sample\cms\download.php on line 109

Comment: Those settings work with XAMPP using mail.php and pear.  I understand wamp has no mail function??

Comment: You said .i got the error my ip is blacklisted - use your usual email sender as the SMTP

Comment: @rhys How do you find out your send? I am on windows but want to send from my linux server that has no problem sending mail...

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) to successfully send emails from my localhost running WAMP.

Try following the instructions [here](http://www.joshstauffer.com/send-test-emails-with-wampserver/) to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Well do you have a mailserver configured on localhost? Otherwise to use mail you will probably have to use you internets provider smtp servers instead of localhost to connect.