# Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to connect to mailserver at “localhost” port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

I used this one however

```
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

I have this error which is Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: So have you followed the suggestion in the error message? *Are* you running a local SMTP server?

Comment: This means that you don't have an SMTP server running on your local machine. Use your ISP or company's SMTP server as the host.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are running your application just on localhost and it is not yet live, I believe it is very difficult to send mail using this.

Once you put your application online, I believe that this problem should be automatically solved.
By the way,ini_set() helps you to change the values in php.ini during run time.

This is the same question as [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

also check this [php mail function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633144/php-mail-function-not-working)