# failed to connect to mailserver at localhost

Tags: php, email

I want to send email to entered email address. But I keep getting this error.

```
 mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

This is my code

```
    <?php
    $email=$_POST["email"];

      $message="Your application has been submitted tothe Incharge and Admin of the classes. Thanks for applying at our insitute.";

      mail($email,"Confirm Application", $message, "From: anemade45@gmail.com");
?>
      <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your email address">
      </form>
```

What should I do to remove that error?

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server) link will help you

Comment: Do you have a mail-server installed on localhost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp\_port" setting in php.ini or use ini\_set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591329/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25-verify-your-smtp-and)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send emails from your localhost unless you have set-up some mail agent, I believe, you can get SMTP settings from email providers such as :

1. Mailgun . https://www.mailgun.com . - they provide 10k emails per month,
2. AWS SES - they have monthly free email plan,

You have to register a domain, even localhost will work to any of these and have to get the SMTP settings